# Spring batch trying to create persistant Batch Job Respository again

Tags: spring, spring-batch

This seems to be a stupid issue. I am trying to configure an Oracle10g database for Spring Batch Job Repository (Spring Batch 2.1.7), I was able to have the tables created using the script available at *org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql* in core. I also set the property *batch.data.source.init* to *false*.

On a clean database my batch program runs fine, successfully creating all the Batch tables/Sequences and populating them with the details of the batch results. However, when I run it again Spring Batch tries to create these tables again and throws "ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object" exception. What am I doing wrong?

```
# For Oracle
batch.jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
batch.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
batch.jdbc.user=****
batch.jdbc.password=****
batch.schema=****
batch.schema.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql
batch.drop.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-oracle10g.sql
batch.jdbc.testWhileIdle=true
batch.data.source.init=false
```

Following is my context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:batch.properties" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myco.mypack" />

    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="${batch.schema.script}" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

    <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/module-context.xml" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />   
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
         <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
         <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
         <property name="databaseType" value="oracle" />
         <property name="tablePrefix" value="BATCH_"/>
         <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_DEFAULT"/>
    </bean>  

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${batch.jdbc.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${batch.jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${batch.jdbc.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${batch.jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: please add the xml configuration where you use the placeholder

Comment: Hi Michael, edited my question to add the XML config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i do not see the use of **batch.data.source.init** like this:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" 
                          enabled="${batch.data.source.init}">
    <jdbc:script location="${batch.schema.script}" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, I had tried even removing this from my XML but it wasn't working earlier, now it works. Also with the "enabled" attribute set to false as you suggested. I am not sure though why the batch.data.source.init doesn't work.

Comment: And may be Michael I can lure you to answer one more trivial newbie question on Spring Batch. Can we create a New job (Schedule a job) or Delete an existing one through the Spring Batch Admin (I see that the guide talks about uploading an XML for adding a job but that seems tedious, if there is an API why shouldn't we be able to create a job on the fly through the Batch Admin Web UI)?

Comment: please add this as a new question so others can find it too :-) for my self i can say - i do not know spring batch admin good enough

Comment: If you copied the code above verbatim, it probably wasn't working because of the # instead of $ on the `enabled` property.

Comment: i am using spring boot and spring 4 with no xml.  I would love to know how to do this, since i have the same problem and none of these solutions apply!

Comment: please add this as another question to stackoverflow

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while but i think for people searching for this problem it will help to know that you can disable creating the databases by using

```
spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false
```

in application.properties as given in the documentation: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Comment: Thanks for this. Had an issue with starting the app crashed at not being able to perform SET TRANSACTION even though I had no DB code. Turns out it was because of the default sql scripts

Answer (score 0):

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" 
                      enabled="${batch.data.source.init}">
<jdbc:script location="${batch.schema.script}" />
```

If I pass Command Line argument -Dbatch.data.source.init=false  ,then the intialization is not enabled.

But If I use the below configuration and set enabled to false in the context xml , then initialisation is triggered even though enabled flag is false

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" 
                      enabled="false">
<jdbc:script location="false" />
```